# How to handle logged in status using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux

I'm a noob, starting my very first project with Node, Express, and React.

I got the authentication working, I have a Component that calls an action, which calls a store (or should), but this is where I get confused. I don't know where to go.

My LoginActions.login makes an api call to login the user, it comes back successfully and stores a cookie with the session ID. After that, how do I tell the UI to go to the dashboard? How do I make the UI KNOW that the user is actually authenticated, and if it's not, kick him out?

Where am I supposed to check for all that? Is it the store? The component itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really "supposed" to do it in any specific way.  React is more of a library than a framework.  You can use it however you see fit.

One option would be to use react-router's `onEnter` function to verify logged in status and user it's replace method to redirect accordingly.

You could also have your components themselves verify logged in status and instead render your login form if not logged in yet.

Or you could even store your login form at a unique uri and handle *all* of the authentication via the server, using 302 redirects based on logged in status.

Up to you!

Comment: Or also use decorator that will check inside your store if isConnected is set to TRUE?

As @gravityplanx said, there's many implementation and lib to do that. You can iterate on it by starting a simple implemenation in your component for exemaple. Then improve it after. This is a simple way to learn without being blocked